# When will velocity and acceleration vectors be perpendicular?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, vectors, geometry

> Suppose a particle is moving in the $xy$ plane with
>   $$x=at, \quad y=at(1-bt),$$
>   where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants. When will the velocity vector and acceleration vector be perpendicular?

I know that these vectors are perpendicular in circular motion. Should I then use the circle equation 
$$ x^2+y^2 = r^2 $$
then substitute $r$ with centripetal acceleration 
$$ a_c = v^2/r $$
and then substitute for $v$? But I don't see how I will get an equation that has something to do with vectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, circular motion is only one of the cases where the acceleration and velocity are perpendicular, you should definitely not be using that.

You have a position vector, $\vec r(t) = [a~t,~~a~t(1-b~t)]$.
Its first and second derivatives are velocity and acceleration vectors, and you want to take the dot product of those two vectors, to see whether that dot product is zero:$$x'(t) x''(t) + y'(t) y''(t) = 0.$$ The first term is trivially zero from the second derivative of $x$, the second derivative of $y$ is a constant that can be divided out unless $a=0$ or $b=0$.

To restate that more physically, your acceleration is constant, and in the y direction. So you are looking for a velocity which is purely in the x direction.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach uses $v\cdot a=\frac{d}{dt}(v^2/2)$, so orthogonality is equivalent to $v^2=\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2=a^2+(a-2abt)^2$ being constant. This is equivalent to $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: This is a very nice approach to the problem as well. Your last sentence is off the mark though.

Comment: @CRDrost Plus it lets us easily prove $v$ is confined to a radius-$|v|$ circle, albeit with no knowledge of how the position therein varies over time, which is the reason why integration doesn't imply that the motion is circular.